# JavaScript try/catch doesn't work when <meta charset="utf-8" /> is defined

Tags: throw

I have a very simple JavaScript function that uses try/catch, though when the meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8" />` is defined on the page, it doesn't work:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function demo(){
    try{
    undefinedfunction()
    alert("I guess you do exist")
    } catch(e){
        alert("An error has occured: "+e.message)
    }
}

</script>

<form method="post">
<b>Demo:</b> <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="demo()" />
</form>
```

In the above case instead of catching the `undefinedfunction()`, the console logs "Syntax Error: illegal character". If I remove the meta tag, the function behaves as expected, alerting a message.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/k0prmk4h/

Comment: Can't reproduce in Firefox 35 on OS X. BTW, your HTML could use validating.

Answer (score 0):

Ah nevermind, it seems the problem was with the spaces inside the function, instead of tabs. I guess "utf-8" is picky about those kinds of things.